# is there a way to accept any branch under the release branch in post-receive?

Tags: bash, git, shell, git-post-receive

I 'm currently pushing to this accept server and, every time that I create a new release, I have to change the BRANCH that is accepted on line 4 of the code, how do I make it so that anything coming from release/ is accepted? I was thinking about something like BRANCH=release/* would that work?

```
#!/bin/bash
TARGET="<path_to_site>"
GIT_DIR="<path_to_repo>"
BRANCH="release/1.7"

while read oldrev newrev ref
do
    # only checking out the master (or whatever branch you would like to deploy)
        if [[ $ref = refs/heads/$BRANCH ]];
        then
                echo "Ref $ref received. Deploying ${BRANCH} branch to production..."
                git --work-tree=$TARGET --git-dir=$GIT_DIR checkout -f

        else
                echo "Ref $ref received. Doing nothing: only the ${BRANCH} branch may be deployed on this server."
        fi
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `==` operator in Bash to do a regex comparison in the `if` statement:

```
if [[ $ref == *"release/"* ]];
then
    # ...
else
    # ...
fi
```

This would match any reference that contains the string `"release/"`, like for example `"refs/heads/release/1.7"`.

Comment: Note that this will also attempt to deploy a push to `refs/tags/release/v1.2` (a newly created *tag* `v1.2`). That might be what you want, and might not.